# CSS need to apply for different portions of html file

Tags: html, css

for example I hava 2 css files

In one css file i have style
              `a{color: blue;}`
   In second file I have 
              `a{color: red;}`

These I wanna apply for my html file

```
      <div>
        <a>first file style </a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a>second file style </a>
      </div>
```

Please suggest, how can I get...Thanks in advance

Comment: first file css will be overridden by second file of css... what exactly you want to do? If you want to apply different css for both anchors then apply class and use css for that...

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? First `a` blue and second `a` red? If yes, you don't need two files

Comment: Not sure of your reasoning as to why you need to have two CSS files, can you not just use the one file and specify based on a class or nth element?

Comment: My problem is - I have 1000 + styles in a file, called a.css & other 1000 + styles in a file, called b.css. I wanna apply a block of html under a.css & other block of html under/according to styles b.css

Answer (score 4):

Set classes

HTML

```
<div>
<a class="blue">first file style </a>
</div>
<div>
<a class="red">second file style </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
a.blue{color: blue;}

a.red{color: red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not using different ID for your < a >  ?

HTML

```
<div>
  <a id="firstlink">first file style </a>
</div>
<div>
  <a id="secondlink">second file style </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#firstlink{ 
  color: blue;
}
#secondlink{
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: yeah, sure, but if he only needs this two link it works fine too..

btw, solution with classes proposed by Luis P.A. is surely better for reusability